# Misclassification rate and total error not going down - neural network debugging

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to do a neural network with one hidden layer from scratch, and my misclassification and error rates are obviously wrong. I can't find my bug and I'm running out of time. Can someone help me? I'll post the rest of the code if needed.

```
def trainNN(Xtrain, ttrain, M, K, W1, W2, iterations,eta):
    N = len(Xtrain)
    Etotal = np.zeros(iterations)
    misclassification_rate = np.zeros(iterations)
    for i in range(iterations):
        dE1_total = np.zeros(W1.shape) 
        dE2_total = np.zeros(W2.shape)
        guesses = []
        count = 0
        true_counter = 0
        cross_entropy = 0
        while count < N: 
            x = Xtrain[count] 
            true_class = ttrain[count]
            y_true = np.zeros(K)
            y_true[true_class] = 1.0
            count += 1

            y,dE1,dE2 = backprop(x,target_y,M,K,W1,W2)

            dE1_total = dE1_total+dE1
            dE2_total = dE2_total+dE2

            cross_entropy = cross_entropy + log_loss(y_true, y)

            guesses.append(y_true.argmax())

            if y.argmax() == y_true.argmax():
                true_counter += 1

        W1 = W1 - eta * dE1_total / N
        W2 = W2 - eta * dE2_total / N
        misclassification_rate[i] = 1 - true_counter / N 
        Etotal[i] = cross_entropy / N


    return W1, W2, Etotal, misclassification_rate, guesses
```

These are my results, as you can see the misclassification rate just goes up and the error as well:

```
(array([[-0.26141859,  0.95582288,  0.57300376,  0.14235966, -0.68768852,
         -0.64548708],
        [-0.93809538,  1.02883521,  0.79944328,  0.12326179, -0.95742711,
          1.18626673],
        [ 0.62943067, -0.40277124, -0.28537253, -0.80926262, -0.39064817,
          0.17429355],
        [-0.15704319, -0.2594925 ,  0.53201345, -0.85378359, -0.41510531,
         -0.09040425],
        [-0.09284687,  0.61627985, -0.50984544, -0.00669883,  0.18498267,
         -0.84636893]]), array([[ 2.1677012 , -1.77665969, -2.88314017],
        [ 0.94825079,  0.90245525,  0.56396907],
        [ 1.46204349, -1.88697652, -1.54105275],
        [ 1.5410913 , -1.79412746, -1.71918361],
        [-0.83947178,  0.78059373, -0.57768823],
        [ 0.32557882, -0.37690341,  0.0395823 ],
        [ 1.93819337, -1.71160783, -0.96436068]]), array([2.99467737, 2.99560225, 2.9965253 , 2.99744653, 2.99836593,
        2.99928353, 3.00019932, 3.00111332, 3.00202552, 3.00293595,
        3.00384459, 3.00475147, 3.00565659, 3.00655995, 3.00746157,
        3.00836144, 3.00925958, 3.01015599, 3.01105067, 3.01194365,
        3.01283491, 3.01372448, 3.01461234, 3.01549852, 3.01638302,
        3.01726584, 3.01814699, 3.01902648, 3.01990431, 3.02078049,
        3.02165503, 3.02252792, 3.02339919, 3.02426882, 3.02513684,
        3.02600325, 3.02686804, 3.02773123, 3.02859283, 3.02945284,
        3.03031126, 3.0311681 , 3.03202337, 3.03287707, 3.03372922,
        3.0345798 , 3.03542884, 3.03627633, 3.03712228, 3.0379667 ,
        3.03880959, 3.03965096, 3.04049082, 3.04132916, 3.04216599,
        3.04300133, 3.04383517, 3.04466752, 3.04549839, 3.04632778,
        3.04715569, 3.04798213, 3.04880712, 3.04963064, 3.05045271,
        3.05127333, 3.05209251, 3.05291026, 3.05372657, 3.05454145,
        3.05535491, 3.05616695, 3.05697758, 3.0577868 , 3.05859461,
        3.05940103, 3.06020606, 3.0610097 , 3.06181195, 3.06261283,
        3.06341233, 3.06421046, 3.06500722, 3.06580263, 3.06659668,
        3.06738938, 3.06818073, 3.06897074, 3.06975942, 3.07054676,
        3.07133277, 3.07211746, 3.07290083, 3.07368289, 3.07446363,
        3.07524307, 3.07602121, 3.07679805, 3.07757359, 3.07834785,
        3.07912083, 3.07989252, 3.08066294, 3.08143208, 3.08219996,
        3.08296657, 3.08373193, 3.08449603, 3.08525888, 3.08602048,
        3.08678084, 3.08753996, 3.08829785, 3.0890545 , 3.08980993,
        3.09056413, 3.09131712, 3.09206889, 3.09281945, 3.09356881,
        3.09431696, 3.09506391, 3.09580966, 3.09655423, 3.0972976 ,
        3.0980398 , 3.09878081, 3.09952064, 3.1002593 , 3.1009968 ,
        3.10173313, 3.10246829, 3.1032023 , 3.10393515, 3.10466685,
        3.10539741, 3.10612682, 3.10685509, 3.10758223, 3.10830823,
        3.1090331 , 3.10975685, 3.11047947, 3.11120098, 3.11192137,
        3.11264065, 3.11335882, 3.11407588, 3.11479184, 3.11550671,
        3.11622047, 3.11693315, 3.11764474, 3.11835524, 3.11906467,
        3.11977301, 3.12048028, 3.12118647, 3.1218916 , 3.12259566,
        3.12329866, 3.12400061, 3.12470149, 3.12540132, 3.12610011,
        3.12679784, 3.12749454, 3.12819019, 3.12888481, 3.12957839,
        3.13027094, 3.13096246, 3.13165296, 3.13234244, 3.1330309 ,
        3.13371834, 3.13440477, 3.13509019, 3.13577461, 3.13645802,
        3.13714042, 3.13782184, 3.13850225, 3.13918168, 3.13986011,
        3.14053756, 3.14121402, 3.14188951, 3.14256402, 3.14323755,
        3.14391011, 3.1445817 , 3.14525232, 3.14592198, 3.14659068,
        3.14725842, 3.14792521, 3.14859104, 3.14925592, 3.14991986,
        3.15058285, 3.15124489, 3.151906  , 3.15256618, 3.15322541,
        3.15388372, 3.1545411 , 3.15519755, 3.15585308, 3.15650769,
        3.15716138, 3.15781415, 3.15846601, 3.15911696, 3.15976701,
        3.16041614, 3.16106438, 3.16171171, 3.16235814, 3.16300368,
        3.16364833, 3.16429209, 3.16493495, 3.16557694, 3.16621803,
        3.16685825, 3.16749759, 3.16813606, 3.16877365, 3.16941036,
        3.17004621, 3.1706812 , 3.17131532, 3.17194858, 3.17258097,
        3.17321252, 3.1738432 , 3.17447304, 3.17510202, 3.17573016,
        3.17635745, 3.17698389, 3.1776095 , 3.17823427, 3.1788582 ,
        3.1794813 , 3.18010356, 3.18072499, 3.1813456 , 3.18196538,
        3.18258434, 3.18320248, 3.1838198 , 3.1844363 , 3.18505199,
        3.18566686, 3.18628093, 3.18689418, 3.18750663, 3.18811828,
        3.18872913, 3.18933917, 3.18994842, 3.19055687, 3.19116453,
        3.1917714 , 3.19237747, 3.19298277, 3.19358727, 3.19419099,
        3.19479393, 3.1953961 , 3.19599748, 3.19659809, 3.19719793,
        3.19779699, 3.19839529, 3.19899282, 3.19958959, 3.20018559,
        3.20078083, 3.20137531, 3.20196903, 3.202562  , 3.20315421,
        3.20374567, 3.20433639, 3.20492635, 3.20551557, 3.20610404,
        3.20669178, 3.20727877, 3.20786502, 3.20845054, 3.20903532,
        3.20961937, 3.21020269, 3.21078528, 3.21136714, 3.21194828,
        3.21252869, 3.21310838, 3.21368735, 3.2142656 , 3.21484313,
        3.21541995, 3.21599606, 3.21657146, 3.21714614, 3.21772012,
        3.21829339, 3.21886596, 3.21943783, 3.22000899, 3.22057946,
        3.22114922, 3.22171829, 3.22228667, 3.22285436, 3.22342135,
        3.22398766, 3.22455328, 3.22511821, 3.22568246, 3.22624602,
        3.22680891, 3.22737112, 3.22793264, 3.2284935 , 3.22905368,
        3.22961318, 3.23017202, 3.23073018, 3.23128768, 3.23184451,
        3.23240068, 3.23295619, 3.23351103, 3.23406521, 3.23461874,
        3.23517161, 3.23572382, 3.23627538, 3.23682629, 3.23737655,
        3.23792615, 3.23847512, 3.23902343, 3.2395711 , 3.24011813,
        3.24066452, 3.24121026, 3.24175537, 3.24229984, 3.24284368,
        3.24338688, 3.24392945, 3.24447139, 3.2450127 , 3.24555338,
        3.24609343, 3.24663286, 3.24717167, 3.24770985, 3.24824741,
        3.24878436, 3.24932068, 3.24985639, 3.25039148, 3.25092596,
        3.25145983, 3.25199309, 3.25252574, 3.25305778, 3.25358921,
        3.25412004, 3.25465026, 3.25517988, 3.2557089 , 3.25623732,
        3.25676514, 3.25729236, 3.25781899, 3.25834503, 3.25887047,
        3.25939532, 3.25991957, 3.26044324, 3.26096633, 3.26148882,
        3.26201073, 3.26253206, 3.2630528 , 3.26357296, 3.26409255,
        3.26461155, 3.26512998, 3.26564783, 3.2661651 , 3.2666818 ,
        3.26719793, 3.26771349, 3.26822848, 3.2687429 , 3.26925676,
        3.26977004, 3.27028277, 3.27079493, 3.27130652, 3.27181756,
        3.27232803, 3.27283795, 3.27334731, 3.27385612, 3.27436437,
        3.27487206, 3.27537921, 3.2758858 , 3.27639184, 3.27689733,
        3.27740228, 3.27790668, 3.27841053, 3.27891384, 3.27941661,
        3.27991883, 3.28042051, 3.28092166, 3.28142227, 3.28192233,
        3.28242187, 3.28292087, 3.28341933, 3.28391726, 3.28441466,
        3.28491153, 3.28540787, 3.28590369, 3.28639897, 3.28689373,
        3.28738797, 3.28788168, 3.28837487, 3.28886754, 3.28935968,
        3.28985131, 3.29034242, 3.29083302, 3.29132309, 3.29181266,
        3.29230171, 3.29279024, 3.29327827, 3.29376578, 3.29425279,
        3.29473928, 3.29522527, 3.29571075, 3.29619573, 3.2966802 ,
        3.29716418, 3.29764764, 3.29813061, 3.29861308, 3.29909505,
        3.29957652, 3.30005749, 3.30053797, 3.30101795, 3.30149744,
        3.30197644, 3.30245494, 3.30293295, 3.30341048, 3.30388751,
        3.30436406, 3.30484012, 3.3053157 , 3.30579078, 3.30626539,
        3.30673951, 3.30721316, 3.30768632, 3.308159  , 3.3086312 ,
        3.30910292, 3.30957417, 3.31004494, 3.31051523, 3.31098506,
        3.3114544 , 3.31192328, 3.31239169, 3.31285962, 3.31332709,
        3.31379408, 3.31426061, 3.31472668, 3.31519227, 3.3156574 ]), array([0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7,
        0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7]), [2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, `           1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 1, 
        1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
        0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 
        1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 
        0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])`
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Plus, question has nothing to do with `jupyter` or `ml` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Well, I am using Jupyter and neural networks is a part of machine learning. But noted.

Comment: I understand but 1) the `jupyter` tag is for questions about Jupyter *itself* 2) the `ml` tag is *not* about machine learning (after all, you have already correctly tagged your question as `machine-learning`) - see the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info).

Comment: Okay, fair enough.